# 2 different URLs to access the same Alfresco instance with Kerberos SSO

Tags: alfresco, kerberos

Using Alfresco Community - 7.1.0, running on a Docker Swarm cluster with Portainer.

I have managed to set up an instance of Alfresco with SSO using Kerberos with an Active Directory server as KDC (with AD users synched through LDAP). All I did was follow the instructions in the Alfresco documentation, so I don't know enough about Kerberos to understand how and why it works.

Right now Alfresco is accessed through a single URL which has the same domain as the AD server (which is also the domain controller). For annoying reasons that I won't go into right now, I need to make this Alfresco accessible through 2 separate external URLs, both of which have
different domains from the AD server.

Do I need to have more than 1 Kerberos realm, or is there a 1 to 1 association between realms and KDCs?

Do I need to map from the internet domain names to the Kerberos realm?

For some reason I'm having a hard time getting my head around this Kerberos stuff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alfresco expects only one REALM.
You need to create for every expected url a separate SPN and put all of them into the one keytab for Alfresco.

At least Windows needs to be configured to trust the other domains for SSO/kerberos authentication by putting them into the intranet zone.

Comment: Hello Robert, this works great, thanks a lot! The solution is a lot simpler than I had imagined.